# How to use multiple event handler text_changed in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 3 text boxes: tbName, tbMiddleName and tbSurname. Below them I have grid which return all people from the SqlServer base. I searched on google how to filter this people by names and see that event handler text_changed do the thing. When I type some name in the tbName it works! I have 130 names in base and when I type "Mike" for example grid shows me all the people which name is Mike - 12. But the problem is when I type "John" in tbMiddleName it canceled the first filter and return me ALL persons which middle name is "John", but I want only people that first name is "Mike", and middle name is "John"(it should return only one guy). Same thing to tbSurname.

Here is my code:

```
    private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text))
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = null;
        }
        else
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = "Name LIKE '%" + tbName.Text + "%'";
        }

    }

    private void tbMiddleName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSifraTransakcije.Text))
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = null;
        }
        else
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = "MiddleName LIKE '%" + tbMiddleName.Text + "%'";
        }
    }

    private void tbSurname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSurname.Text))
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = null;
        }
        else
        {
            bsAllPeople.Filter = "Surname LIKE '%" + tbSurname.Text + "%'";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just expand your filter: "Name LIKE [...] AND MiddleName LIKE [...] AND Surname LIKE [...]" - you may have to check if the names are actually filled in, but that should do it.

Comment: You have to use general expression for all three params. But you shouldnt use sql queries in such maner - it vunerable to sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't about several text changed handlers, it is about creating filters.

I think in your particular case you could use one shared text chaned event handler for all of your three text boxes.

In this event handler you have to create a filter like

```
"Name LIKE '%" + tbName.Text + "%' AND MiddleName LIKE '%" + tbMiddleName.Text + "%'"
```

Comment: Tnx Chris, tnx to germi too. So easy! Germi, I understand you, but it is always better to type code like Chris. Cheers mates! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just make another method that will handle the filter.

```
public void Refilter()
{
    bsAllPeople.Filter = $"Name LIKE '%{tbName.Text}%' AND MiddleName LIKE '%{tbMiddleName.Text}%' AND Surname LIKE '%{tbSurname.Text}%'";
}
```

and use it like this

```
private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refilter();
}
```

**Note:** Please search about Parameterize SQL Query, SQL Injection.

Comment: Tnx to all you guys, so quick answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
`private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  bsAllPeople.Filter = "Name LIKE '%" + tbName.Text + "%' and MiddleName LIKE 
  '%" + tbMiddleName.Text + "%' and Surname LIKE '%" + tbSurname.Text + "%'";
 }`
```

call this event on all textboxes change event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you override `Filter` property of `bsAllPeople` and not checking if there are any other filters present.

A better practise would be to have a method which builds one filter statement from all your TextBoxes. You call the method whenever any of the TextBoxes changes.

You could do something like this, which is a little bit ugly i admit, but as long as you have only three TextBoxes still okay. If you have more a larger or variant number you should go for a clever routine building filters and consider the `StringBuilder` class, but this is another topic.

```
var filter = string.Empty;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text))
{
    filter += "Name LIKE '%" + tbName.Text + "%'";
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSifraTransakcije.Text))
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        filter += " AND ";
    }

    filter += "MiddleName LIKE '%" + tbMiddleName.Text + "%'";
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSurname.Text))
{
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        filter += " AND ";
    }

    filter += "Surname LIKE '%" + tbSurname.Text + "%'";

}

bsAllPeople.Filter = filter;
```